# how can i add a product to a cart via ajax request in shopware 6

Tags: ajax, shopware, shopware6

I have implemented a product configurator and I want to enable users to add a configured product to their shopping cart when they click on the "Request" button.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
var lineItemsData = {
        lineItems: [
            {
                "id": productId,
                "quantity": 1,
                "type": 'product'
            }
        ]
    };

  jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "/checkout/line-item/add",
      data: lineItemsData,
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function(response) {
        console.log("Product added to cart successfully");
        console.log(response); 
      }
    });
```

However, when I click the "Request" button, I consistently receive 400 or 500 errors, and the product is not added to the cart as expected. I added a configurator with HTML tag and JavaScript inside a layout and want to make a request there as well.

Comment: Please consult the official documentation of the Store API: https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/store-api/c42e41eaf2490-add-items-to-the-cart